# Shortening array in Java

Tags: java, arrays

Part of my code has this in it.

```
public void drawBoard(){
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++){
            board[i][j] = null;
        }
    }

    board[0][1] = new Piece(false);
    board[1][1] = new Piece(false);
    board[2][1] = new Piece(false);
    board[3][1] = new Piece(false);
    board[4][1] = new Piece(false);
    board[5][1] = new Piece(false);
    board[6][1] = new Piece(false);
    board[7][1] = new Piece(false);
}
```

Is there a way I could shorten it besides declaring the position of each element one by one?

Comment: Why don't you write a for loop?

Comment: Better still, an 8x8 board can be represented as a single dimensional array indexed 0-63

Comment: Aren't elements of an array of objects declared, by default, as null? Or does drawBoard() just implicitly reset the board? You might be able to simplify by initializing board, but it is hard to tell with just a snippet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
public void drawBoard(){
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++){
            board[i][j] = null;

        }
        board[i][1] = new Piece(false);
    }
}
```

For kicks, if you represented an 8x8 board using a 1D array, you could do the same thing in this manner, eliminating a loop.

```
public void drawBoard() {
    int j = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++) {
        // j represents your "column"
        // every 8 counts, a new column is found
        if ( i % 8 == 0 ) {
            j++;
        }

        // for the '1' column, set your piece, else null
        board[i] = ( j == 1) ? new Piece(false) : null;
    }
}
```